# The number of ways to find unique numbers that sum to a number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.5

This is the description of the problem:

> There is a list of integers, `sequence`. There is another integer argument, `target`. The objective is to return the number of unique ways `target` can be expressed as the sum of four distinct numbers in `sequence`.

This is my code:

```
def __main__(sequence, target):
    big = 0
    for elem in sequence:
        for elem_ in sequence:
            for _elem_ in sequence:
                for _elem__ in sequence:
                    if (elem + elem_ + _elem_ + _elem__ == target):
                        big+=1
    print(str(big))        
__main__([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 6)
```

The algorithm seems fine to me. But I keep getting the answer `2400` for this, when according to the test case, the answer should be `60`. I suspect I'm going over one method four times, but then again dividing `2400` by `4` does not give you `60`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations()`:

```
import itertools

def sums(lst, n):
  count = 0

  for sample in list(itertools.combinations(lst, 4)):
    if sum(sample) == n:
      count += 1
  
  return count

print(sums([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 6)) # => 60
```

From the docs:

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.
>
> ```
> combinations(range(4), 3) # --> 012 013 023 123
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def sums(sequence, target):
    n = len(sequence)
    total = 0

    for i1 in range(n):
        v1 = sequence[i1]
        for i2 in range(i1+1, n):
            v2 = sequence[i2]
            for i3 in range(i2+1, n):
                v3 = sequence[i3]
                for i4 in range(i3+1, n):
                    v4 = sequence[i4]
                    if v1+v2+v3+v4 == target:
                        total += 1

    return total

def main():
    print(sums([2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 6))

main()
```

This ensures that each list element is used at most once, and gives the desired result of 60.

The looping is a little less concise than I'd like, but it's efficient, and doesn't require any temporary list slices.